# Generate pdf from print view screen

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, printing

I want to generate pdf what displayed in window print view screen. Is it possible?
I have a problem to generate pdf through the mpdf and tcpdf so i want to generate pdf through the print screen which will be display print view.